# Removing Zero from Beginning of 24 Hour Time conversion

Tags: javascript, parseint, datetime-conversion

This is for a problem on Time Conversion from the 12-hour format to the military/24-hour time.
The standard input: `07:05:45PM`
The expected output: `19:05:45`
The standard/actual output: `019:05:45`
The problem lies in the zero **^** at the beginning of the output.

I tried to set the `parseInt()` with a radix of 10 for the decimal numeral system but that didn't have any effect.

This is a result of this following code :

```
function main() {
  var time = readLine();

  var hours = parseInt(time.substr(0, 2), 10);
  var minutes = parseInt(time.substr(3,5));
  var seconds = parseInt(time.substr(6,8));

  if ( time.indexOf('AM') !== -1 && hours === 12) {
    time = time.replace('12', '00');
  }
  if (time.indexOf('PM') !== -1 && hours < 12) {
    time = time.replace(hours, (hours + 12));
  }

  time = time.replace(/(AM|PM)/g, '');
  console.log(time);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try this:    hours = +hours

Comment: I don't see what you mean. Where are you thinking that should be put?

Comment: time = time.replace(hours, (hours + 12));

Comment: in this line, try this

Comment: time = time.replace(hours, (+(hours + 12));

Comment: Muhammed, using replace is a bad idea, and will cause issues, check out my answer.

Comment: why parse out minutes and seconds if you don't use those values?

Comment: You're right, it was unnecessary for that solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just rebuild the string instead of using replace. Because you're using replace in your example you're just replacing the 7 with 19. Using replace will also cause issues if you have a time like 12:12:12.

ex.

```
function main() {
  var time = readLine();

  var hours = parseInt(time.substr(0, 2), 10);
  var minutes = time.substr(3,5);
  var seconds = time.substr(6,8);

  if ( time.indexOf('AM') !== -1 && hours === 12) {
    hours = 0;
  }
  else if (time.indexOf('PM') !== -1 && hours < 12) {
    hours += 12;
  }

  time = (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
  console.log(time);
}
```

Comment: That works for the most part! I just had to add a conditional for the each of hours/minutes/seconds to include a zero if they are less than 10: `time = hours + ':' + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ':' + (seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);`

Comment: Yeah, I missed that Jon, I updated it to fix the issue. There's no point converting minutes and seconds to integers there fine as strings, it removes the need for conditionals on those variables, but you should do the conditional for hours.

Comment: Thank you! Although, it looks like if I don't convert them to integers, I'm still getting the AM/PM coming into the output, which is weird, since `substr()` should be handling that. I'm going to leave it with the conversion and the conditionals to pass the test cases, but I'll definitely look into why it is still doing that without them. Thank you for the help Jacob!